# Windows Server 2012 NIC Teaming "Host unmanageable" issue

Tags: windows-server-2012

Windows Server 2012 NIC Teaming issue. When trying to create a team the following error appears:
"Host unmanageable"
When trying to add a couple of nics to create a team all nics are listed as cannot be added to a team.

How do you reset this information so it allows nic teaming?

Answer (score 2):

The "solution" is not to edit wmi or registry, apparently the lbfoadmin tool caches only the last session opened.

To open it correctly use the server manager under local server section or run `lbfoadmin /servers .`, which is what the server manager does.

Answer (score 2):

I had tried all the tips on the internet and the solution was simple.
Instead of going to Local Server to open the NIC Team, I had to go to ALL Servers.

It sounds ridiculous but it worked in my case.

open server manager Click in all servers select your server right click in your server and open NIC TEAM

Answer (score 1):

The [explanation as appears in MS forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/421b7988-c224-457e-a1d2-6d848db93f8f/nic-teaming-host-unmanageable), please have a look:

"Hi,

Please check whether NIC teaming is enabled in your server:

Open Server Manager --> in the console tree, click Local Serer --> in the details pane, in the Properties section, check NIC Teaming status.

To configure NIC Teaming on a server
1.Click the server name in the list of servers (even if there is only a single server).
2.From the Tasks drop-down menu in the Teams section, click New Team. 
3.In the Add Team dialog box, type a team name and select the network adapters in the team. 
4.If you are using VLANs, clear the Default check box and specify the VLAN ID. By default, the team will deliver up all traffic received regardless of VLAN ID (though the VLAN ID is passed with the packet so that other components in the stack can sort them appropriately).
5.If you want to use a mode other than the default, click Advanced and specify the teaming mode (Switch Independent, Static Teaming, or LACP) and load distribution mode (Address Hash) as needed.
6.Click OK to create the team.

The Address Hash option for the load distribution mode is the 4-tuple   hash previously described. PowerShell cmdlets for NIC Teaming allow you to   configure other address hashing modes.

7.To modify the settings of a network adapter team, click the team name in the list of teams, and then click Modify team in the list of tasks.

For more information please refer to following MS articles:

NIC Teaming Overview
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831648.aspx

NIC Teaming in Windows Server 2012 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/privatecloud/archive/2012/06/19/nic-teaming-in-windows-server-2012-brings-simple-affordable-traffic-reliability-and-load-balancing-to-your-cloud-workloads.aspx

Hope this helps!
"

Comment: Thanks for the help but the issue is not how to configure the NIC teaming. The issue is that the server is listed as non responding because of a previous Intel Proset issue which has now had the registry cleaned. The nics have been tested and are working fine. The nics can be setup in a team with intel Proset/Dell teaming software just fine but I want to use Microsoft teaming.                                                             Reference to what I changed: [link](http://www.dell.com/support/article/jm/en/jmbsdt1/SLN290411/en?c=jm&s=bsd&cs=jmbsdt1&l=en)

Comment: Thanks for the help but the issue is not how to configure the NIC teaming. The issue is that I can not assign the nics to a MS team because of a previous Intel Proset issue which has now had the registry cleaned. The nics can be used in an Intel Proset team working fine with intel Proset/Dell teaming software just fine but I want to use Microsoft teaming.                                                           Reference to what I changed: [Uninstall IntelProset Software that failed to remove properly](http://www.dell.com/support/article/jm/en/jmbsdt1/SLN290411/en?c=jm&s=bsd&cs=jmbsdt1&l=en)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to fix Host managability issue

1. net stop winmgmt
2. rename the folder 'Repository' underneath %windir%\system32\wbem
3. restart the system
4. winmgmt /resetrepository
5. gpupdate /force
6. disable all the network adapters
7. remove HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\Config
8. enable all the network adapters

enable nic teaming

**It worked after this process was completed.**

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to click on the line where it states "Host Unmanageable" and then from the pop-up menu select "Use Credentials...". From the next window, I entered in credentials for a local administrator account that was on the remote host.